# Is -7/3 equivalent to 2/12? If so how?

Tags: linear-algebra

here's a link to the video of a guy solving an algebraic equation on YouTube and he says that that is the answer. Go to 4:11 on the video [video with equation on it](https://youtu.be/bEMIicZhUCM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem he is solving is

$\frac {x+3}4 = \frac 2{12}$.

and he is asking what is $x$.

Now $x$ will *not* be $\frac 2{12}$.  $\frac {x+3}4 = \frac 2{12}$.

He does the proble to solve for $x$ and  gets that

$x =\frac {-28}{12}$.  That is what !!!$x$!!! is.  And it *not* what $\frac 2{12}$ is.  The original $\frac 2{12}$, where refered to $\frac {x+3}4$ is gone and we are not talking about it anymore.  FOr that matter we are no longer talking about $\frac {x+3}4$.  That *also* is gone, and we are only interested in $x$.

Remember !!!$x$!!!! is a number and we are just trying to figure out what *it* is:

$\frac {x+3}4 = \frac 2{12} \implies$

$12(x+3) = 4*2 \implies$ (note: we are no longer talking about $\frac 2{12}$ nor about $\frac {x+3}4$... let go of the past, man...)

$12x + 36 = 8 \implies$

$12x = 8-36 = -28\implies$ (note: we are no longer talking about $12(x+3)$ or $12x + 36$ or $8$.... let it go, let it go....)

$x = \frac {-28}{12}$.  And now we are no longer talking about $12x$ or $-28$ what's done is done; it's how we got here, and we owe it our thanks but in the here and now, we are talking about $x$.

And we found $x = \frac {-28}{12}$..... which is the same thing as $\frac {-3}2$.  But none of them have anything to do with $\frac 2{12}$ which was what $\frac {x+3}4$ was.  And $\frac {x+3}4$ was something *entirely* different.

=====

Perhaps an anology:

We start with $x + 2 = 7$

So that means $x = 5$.  But we started with $7$ and ended with $5$?  Does that mean $7 = 5$?

Of course not.  The first part we were talking about  $x+2$ being $7$.  In the second part we are talking about $x$ *which* is *ENTIRELY* different that $x+2$.  So one thing is $7$ and the *other* thing is $5$.  That doesn't mean $7$ and $5$ are the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I got it since my previous post,  I thought he meant that, so at first I was confused,how could that mean that I thought? but then I understood that I didn't take all variables into consideration

Answer (score 1):

At 5:03 in the video, the maker of the video writes the fraction $\frac{-28}{12}$, which he explains can be reduced to $\frac{-7}{3}$.

It is unclear how your question about $\frac 2{12}$ is connected to this video.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah he simplified it, I understood that part but I miscalculated, I didn't take into account the x+3 ÷4, so (-7/3)+3÷4 should equal 2/12 like he said,  I didn't take into account that part I just saw -7/3 and thought he meant it equaled 2/12, thanks anyways